# How to get the android app detail like package name and others

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am working with **MIT App Inventor** and the `activity starter` component.

I have to know the app class, package detail and others, so how can I get all this information for any app?

Moreover I want to send SMS using `activity starter` from ICQ messenger to a specific contact. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For **App Inventor** this is explained in the documentation: [Using the Activity Starter](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/activitystarter.html)

> **Discovering how to set the ActivityStarter properties**
>
> If you want to start an app and you you don't have the source code or
>   documentation, you might still be able figure out the package name and
>   class name (and sometimes the intent) by launching the app and
>   inspecting the Android system log. For example, if you use the YouTube
>   application to play a video, you'll see in the log:
>
> **I/ActivityManager(   86): Starting activity: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=vnd.youtube:nAPk9ycCbfc
>   cmp=com.google.android.youtube/.PlayerActivity }**
>
> If you can find the "cmp=" string, then the ActivityPackage is the
>   part before the slash, e.g.,  com.google.android.youtube.  The
>   ActivityClass is is the entire "cmp=" part, without the slash
>   character, e.g., com.google.android.youtube.PlayerActivity.   There
>   may also in general be "dat=" information that should be specify as
>   the DataUri property.

**How to use Logcat**

I normally use Eclipse and Logcat there, but if you have installed the App Inventor Software (see also http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/setup-emulator.html), you already have everything you need to use logcat...

1. connect your device using USB with your computer in File Manger
2. go to the App Inventor directory, which is  C:\Program Files\App
   Inventor or similar
3. press Shift and right mouse click the
   subdirectory commands-for-Appinventor to get the context menu
4. select "open command window here" and you will get a command window of that
   subdirectory
5. enter adb logcat and the logcat will start running

Answer (score 0):

Here is the class name ApplicationInfo [Developer doc link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html) which gives you most of the detail of Application(installed in phone).

You can get list of Apps installed in the phone via below method.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
```

you can get applicatio info by looping above list. For packageName, can follow below code.

```
 for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : apps) {
        //Package Name
        String temp =  packageInfo.packageName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this information from PackageManager:

```
        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        // get a list of installed apps.
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        // loop through the list of installed packages and see if the selected
        // app is in the list
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {

            //Get Package Name
            String packageName=packageInfo.packageName;

            // get the UID for the selected app
            int UID = packageInfo.uid;

            ApplicationInfo app = null;
            try {
                app = pm.getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          //Get App Name
           String appName=pm.getApplicationLabel(app);

        //likewise you can get other information
        }
```